# Why dynamic view erb file in rails from hash not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, erb

All,
to compose dynamically a `search.html.erb` view, we are storing the details of each field that needs to be displayed as a hash or a hash represented as a string in a table. E.g. to display a `status` field, we are storing the related `status` layout as follow:

```
{:status => {:label => 'Status', :collection => return_misc_definitions('project_status') } }
```

Then my search.html.erb has the below pseudo code

```
<%= simple_form_for @model,  :method => :put, :url => @search_results_url  do |f| %>
      <%= @fields_details.each do |field, layouts| %>
          <%= f.input field, eval(layouts) %>
      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The goal is to end up with something like

```
<%= f.input :status, :label => 'Status', :collection => return_misc_definitions('project_status') %>
```

We are using the `eval` function of the "layout", but this is not working as the eval tries to evaluation the function `return_misc_definitions`. How can I escape this evaluation? We are using `ruby 1.9.3`, `rails 3.2.12` and `simple_form`. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<% @fields_details = {:status => {:label => 'Status', :collection => [1,2,3,4]} } %>

<%= simple_form_for :form,  :method => :put, :url => @search_results_url  do |f| %>
  <% @fields_details.each do |field, layouts| %>
    <%= f.input field, layouts %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I removed the `=` in `<%= @fields_details.each do |field, layouts| %>` to prevent `@field_details` from rendering on the screen then just passed the field and layouts into Simple Form directly, no eval necessary.

Comment: Hi Josh. Thanks for you suggestion. my issue that currently we are storing {:status => {:label => 'Status', :collection => [1,2,3,4]} } as a string in a table, I needed to apply an eval to turn it into a hash of a hash, also the :collection is mapped to a customer function that retrieve a list of status.

Comment: One question, why would you store `return_misc_definitions` if you didn't want it evaluated at runtime?

Comment: we want it to be evaluated at runtime. But because I was applying the "eval" to turn the string (stored in db) into a hash of a hash, that is when the eval tries also to evaluate this custom function and fails